Majority vote EM category
I am working with the multiset monad.  I want the EM category to have a structure map that is majority vote.  That is to say that the map $f: X \rightarrow M(X)$ takes the set element with the highest multiplicity and returns the set element.  To do this, I want to define the imbalanced multiset monad as given by a triple $\mathcal{M} = \langle M, \mu_M, \eta_M \rangle$, where

$M$ is a functor.  $M: Set \rightarrow Set$ where $Set$ is the category of sets and functions.  It takes a set to the set of imbalanced multisets on that set.  Imbalanced multisets always have an element with the maximum multiplicity.
$\mu_M$ is a natural transformation called the product natural transformation.  $\mu_M : M \cdot M \rightarrow M$.  This takes a set of imbalanced multisets of imbalanced multisets to a set of imbalanced multisets.  It works by dissolving the inner ``bags'' and returning one big bag.
$\eta_M$ is a natural transformation.  $\mu: I \rightarrow M$ and acts by taking taking a set to a set of imbalanced multisets, one for each set element.  For example the set element $a$ goes to $\{ a \}$.

Will this work?
Also, there is a well known monad map from the multiset monad to the distribution monad and so I expect a monad map from the imbalanced multiset monad to the unimodal distribution monad.  The structure map for the EM category for this monad returns the set element of the mode.
Will this work?

You haven't defined "imbalanced", but I doubt you can do so in a way that $\mu$ always gives an imbalanced multiset. Assuming you mean "there is a unique element with highest multiplicity", consider e.g. ${{a, a, a, b}, {a, b, b}, {a, b, b}}$.

@NaïmFavier, yes, back to the drawing board

@NaïmFavier I am having a second thought.  What f the structure map for the EM category of the distrubution sends back a set, which is the set of all modes of the distribution.  We couldn't define this on Set, but what if we define it on something like a category of powersets.  Like, is there a category where the objects are the powersets of all sets?  I think this won't work, but let me know if you have any thoughts.  Also, look at this new post of mine.
